# Opening a websocket channel inside MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Has anyone has any good experience with opening a websocket connection inside MVC controller?

**Technology stack:** ASPNET Core 1.0 (RC1) MVC, dnx46, System.Net.WebSockets

**Why MVC instead of middleware:** for overall consistency, routing, already injected repositories, an option to call private methods in the same controller.

```cs
[HttpGet("v1/resources/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string id)
{
    var resource = await this.repository.GetAsync(id);
    if (resource == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
    }

    if (this.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        var webSocket = await this.HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        if (webSocket != null && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var response = string.Format("Hello! Time {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                await webSocket.SendAsync(new System.ArraySegment<byte>(bytes),
                    WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        }
    }

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(101);           
}
```

**Question:** are there any known downsides going with way instead of handling a websocket connections in a middleware? How about the handshake, do we need to do anything else in addition to returning HTTP 101 status code?

**Update 1: why not SignalR?** there is no need to use fallback techniques, so while it's a good product, it see no benefit of adding additional dependency in this situation.

**Update 2:** one downside I've already noticed - when the while(true) exists (for simplicity reasons, not shown in an example above, let' say, when a channel needs to be closed), the methods needs to return something (Task). What it should be? HTTP 200 status response? I guess no, because in the WebSockets documentation is written, that nothing should be sent after the "close" frame.

**Update 3:** one thing I learned the hard way, that if you want to get WebSockets working while debugging in Visual Studio 2015 using IIS Express 10.0 on Windows 10, you still have to use https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets and configure app.UseWebSockets() in your Startup.cs file. Otherwise, IsWebSocketRequest will be false. Anyone knows why? Handshake?

Comment: Use SignalR
http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: I've had success mixing websocketsharp with MVC6 / MVC Core 1.0 / whatever they are calling it this week. Things do not go through the OWIN middleware pipeline, but you can run a web socket server on a different port and have it service the WS connections. Just food for thought.

Comment: Unverified, but I suspect that the "most right" way to do this is to define your own custom implementation of `IActionResult`, with the websocket loop inside its `ExecuteResultAsync` method. Then the controller just returns an instance of that.

Comment: I just did this – I put the websocket handling loop inside ExecuteResultAsync of a custom IActionResult class. This avoids an issue of other middleware trying to set stuff in OnStartup, but headers already being sent.

Comment: Could you please kindly share with us your final implementation on how you got a WebSocket running inside an action method in asp.net MVC 5?

Comment: I have a partial answer to the "Question" part at the end of the post. From what I have read on MDN regarding protocol upgrading, it must be initiated by the client, (except in the case of TLS). Only return 101 if the request contained an "Upgrade" header. You also need to include the "Upgrade" header in the response, stating the protocol you are switching to, and a "Connection" header like so:

    Connection: Upgrade
    Upgrade: websocket  

[MDN: Protocol upgrade mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems fine.

- You probably want to change the `while(true)` to `while (!HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)` so you detect client disconnects and end the request.
- You don't need to check for null or the state of the websocket after you call accept.

I'm assuming all of that code is temporary and you'll actually be reading something from the websocket.

All the usual websocket rules apply:

- Use SSL (when you're hosting it forreal)
- It won't work on multiple servers (it's a point to point socket connection)
- You need to support handling partial frames. You can punt this if you know the client won't send any.

Comment: Thanks, great tips! I won't be reading from the socket on the server side.