# Is it possible to use the same router in multiple middlewares?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Startup.cs I want to configure 2 middlewares:

1. An app.Use (or app.Map with app.Use) which handles websocket requests, but requires a specific dynamic route endpoint.
2. app.UseMvc() with attribute routing.

How the router can be created and reused in MVC in such situation?

PS. Here is my related question where I am looking at the same problem from a different perspective: [Opening a websocket channel inside MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554128/opening-a-websocket-channel-inside-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and after checking the sources I found that the `UseMvc` method creates its own instance of `RouteBuilder` and `IRouter`. This means that you have no control over the route creation while using `UseMvc`.

So I can suggest creating an alternative to `UseMvc` that will create two routes mapped to different handlers, one to Mvc and the second to Websocket. Though I haven't tested it yet, hope it helps.